# AzureAD SAML response

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, assertion

Does AzureAD support *SessionNotOnOrAfter* attribute of "AuthnStatement" section in SAML response?
If not, can we consider *NotBefore* and *NotOnOrAfter* attributes of "Conditions" section as valid session time window (session length)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, The `NotBefore` and `NotOnOrAfter` attributes specify the interval during which the assertion is valid.

```
<Conditions NotBefore="2013-03-18T07:38:15.128Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-03-18T08:48:15.128Z">
      <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>https://www.contoso.com</Audience>
      </AudienceRestriction>
</Conditions>
```

- The value of the `NotBefore` attribute is equal to or slightly (less than a second) later than the value of `IssueInstant` attribute of the `Assertion` element. Azure AD does not account for any time difference between itself and the cloud service (service provider), and does not add any buffer to this time.
- The value of the `NotOnOrAfter` attribute is 70 minutes later than the value of the `NotBefore` attribute.

Reference: [Single Sign-On SAML protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-on-protocol-reference)

Answer (score 3):

As of today, AzureAD does not support SessionNotOnOrAfter attribute and does not allow to configure session lifetimes derived from the SAML Response. The "NotOnOrAfter" attribute should not be used to control session lifetime, because it has totally different meaning and purpose. See [NotOnOrAfter in SubjectConfirmationData and Conditions and SessionNotOnOrAfter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508906/notonorafter-in-subjectconfirmationdata-and-conditions-and-sessionnotonorafter).