# Google SAML assertion expiration time

Tags: google-oauth, saml-2.0, google-authentication

How much time is SAML assertion valid, after I got a successful response to my callback url?

My use case: I want to be able to send requests to a 3rd party web sever from my web server, and I would like to authenticate my user using this SAML assertion. That's why I ask about its expiration time.

Comment: [SAML-2.0 - NotOnOrAfter in SubjectConfirmationData and Conditions and SessionNotOnOrAfter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508906/notonorafter-in-subjectconfirmationdata-and-conditions-and-sessionnotonorafter)

Answer (score 0):

The assertion should have a NotBefore and NotAfter to give you the validity period.  if it does not your application should enforce a maximum time range